# UTF8 character_set_server and DataTables plugin

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, utf-8, datatables

My `UTF8` data looks mangled using windows software to connect to the database and look at the data.
Although my PHP script functions just fine though (both reading and writing).

I have tried my script on my localhost and everything is great and it looks fine too when viewed from a client. But on the shared hosts server things are different.

From what I can gather the only difference is the character_set_server is `latin1` whereas on my local server its `utf8`:

```
| character_set_client     | utf8                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                   |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                 |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                   |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                 |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                   |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/             |
```

I can sort of fix this issue by issuing a `SET NAMES UTF8` which encodes the data correctly into the server.

But doing this causes `DataTables` Jquery plugin to fail to show the field. According to the author it wont show a field if its not in correct `UTF8` format.

Whats going on? Can I fix this if I don't have root access to change the setting of the server?

Comment: First, let's decide whether the data was mangled on _input_ or on _output_.  Please provide output of `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` fetching some mangled column from some table.

Comment: @Rick James Value of "£25" HEX = C382C2A33235.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `£25` was stored as HEX `C382 C2A3 32 35`, you have the "double encoding" problem that I discuss in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).

*Probably* what happened is that you had `£25` encoded in utf8 (hex: C2A3 32 35; the 32 35 is '25') when you were inserting it.  But you declared the *client* was using latin1.  (This is the default in many situations, but it was wrong here.)  Meanwhile, you had the column declared to be `CHARACTER SET utf8`.  (Checkpoint:  Does my analysis sound correct?)

So, MySQL trusted what you said and converted `C2 A3 32 35` as if it were latin1 into utf8.  latin1 `C2` became utf8 `C382` and latin1 `A3` became utf8 `C2A3`.  (The `2` and `5` did not change; the encoding is the same in both character sets.)

If you read it back with the client wrongly declared latin1, the steps will be reversed, and you won't know anything is wrong.  But, apparently, your second client is declared differently.  (Checkpoint:  Does this sound correct?)

You should fix the client that is inserting things incorrectly, and you should fix the data.  These are two separate tasks that should be done essentially at the same time.  The blog explains it, but may not be easy to tease out.  What would you like to do at this point?

Comment: Yes I think your right on the double encoding points. On my second client Ive manually set the server to handle UTF8 by changing the my.ini config file.  So how do I fix this on the problematic server? I only have 3 records that need UTF8 so they can be changed manually. Do I need to change the table or issue a command PHP command to fix subsequent insert/updates ?  I remember when I do things correctly and get a HEX value of C2A33235 DataTables refused to show the fields contents (invalid utf8 data).

Comment: It might be easiest and safest to manually update the rows.  Do you know what they should say, and are the strings a manageable size?

Comment: Well I did play around with the database and I got the right values, for example £25 = C2A33235 right?  But when its like this Datatables doesnt show any fields, it only seems to like Double encoded fields.  If I could change the character_set_server I think I could fix this problem.

Comment: If you get truncated strings (empty string in that case), you probably _inserted_ latin1 bytes while `SET NAMES utf8` was in effect.  If you can see / not see the string during `SELECT`, I would like to here more details.